# Loop in a URL Django

Tags: django, django-urls

I wanted to access different categories through the URL, is it possible to make a loop or something like that? Which iterates until the end of the URL, no matter how much categories are there.

For example my code without this loop is below, and is limited to 6 subcategories.

*urls.py*

`path('<cat1>/<cat2>/<cat3>/<cat4>/<cat5>/<cat6>', views.AdList.as_view(), name='ad_list'),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the easiest way to go would be to add multiple urls to your `urlpatterns` pointing to the same view.

For instance:

```py
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

# if you really want urls being abled to "receive" one to 6 categories in such a way:
for i in range(1, 6):
    new_url = 'cars/'
    for j in range (0, i):
        new_url += f"<str:cat{j}>/"
    urlpatterns.append(path(r'f{new_url}', your_view.as_view(), name="your_view")
```

This will work, because you can have multiple urls pointing to the same view. Then, you will have to check in your view whether or not such category is provided or not.

Comment: It's an ads website, so I wanted the categories to be in the URL for Google purposes, like /cars/pickups/Ford/F-150/gasoline/new.

So I need something like the reverse of it, which listen the url independent of how much cats are there and then convert it in a array.

Comment: Well I'm not sure you can do such a thing with a number of categories unknown. What about something like: `path(/<str:cat1>/<str:cat2>/<str:cat3>/<str:cat4>/<str:cat5>/', views.YourView.as_view(), name="your_view")`? You could then get `cat` values in your view. But, you will always need to put a value for each. Does that help?

Comment: @cainanan I just updated my answer. Is it something like that you'd like? Same view but for different urls

Comment: Well, nice idea! We're in the way, I'd just ident the 'append' part in the 'for' loop.
So, I'll have a maximum of subcategories there, right? Is there a way to dinamically get the number of subcategories (or "/" bars) and deal with it?

Comment: Well maybe, but I'm not sure it would be 100% errorless. You could loop on i for i in range(1,6), then just `try... except...` to get the value (which would be `cat{i}`).
To me, there was no need to ident! but if the result is good for you, that's what matters :-)